# List of software for finding closed form of floating point number (a numeric approximation).

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

The number 10.3500574150076 is a numeric approximation of $\log(2)^2+\pi^2$. If we do not know its closed form and want to find it using computer, then there are a few things we may tre:

- Inverse Symbolic Calculator ([ISC](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/F/floating_point_number.html))
- [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com)
- Maple's [`identify`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=identify) function.
- The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences ([oeis](https://oeis.org/)).

By asking my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2310547/1618), I also learned a new one.

- [RIES](http://mrob.com/pub/ries) by Robert Munafo.

Is there any other software that may be helpful for this kind of task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question, but a comment too long to be put in the comments section.

I don't know if they are other public softwares than those in the large list already given.

For the record, it will be noted that one of the first software of this kind was developed by Simon Plouffe , Laboratoire de combinatoire et d'informatique mathématique de l'UQAM, Québec University, Montréal(Canada) and in the IUT Informatique de Nantes (France). Unfortunately, the public access to the so called "Plouffe Inverter" is no longer available.

I would like to give another viewpoint about these kind of softwares. This concerns the computer students and more precisely mathematical software development.

Developing a basic form of software of this kind is not so complicated that one think at first sight. This could be an excellent training for students learning data processing and computational science : That is why I pick that point up here.

Even with a small computer rather slow and of low capacity, already remarkable results can be observed. For example, with a personal computer of old generation, the example proposed by ablmf (10.3500574150076 ) is solved in an acceptable time. The solution $(\ln(2))^2+\pi^2$ appears in top place on the list of approximate formulas found :

[image]

The symbols are : p=$\pi$ , c=Catalan constant, g=Euler-Mascheroni constant, sh=$\sinh$, ch=$\cosh$, ...

The general principle to write such a software is roughly described in the paper (in French) :  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14161596/Mathematiques-experimentales

Comment: Hi Jean ! The link "seems" to be broken.

Comment: Hi Claude ! This is strange, the link works well from my place. Would you try : https://fr.scribd.com/user/10794575/JJacquelin and see if you can see the document in the list ? Thank you. Jean

Comment: *Le principe de la tartine beurrée !* Now, it works !! By the way, what is the link to what you show (which I don't see) ?Thanks.

Comment: Well, I cannot say why the links sometimes work or not. The first link is a direct access to a particular document. The second link is supposed to give access to a full list of documents.

Comment: Is this a software from you ? By the way, I enjoyed your paper. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest in the  referenced paper. Yes, it's  an homemade software written a long time ago. Realizing that it was much easier to make it than expected, gave me the idea to write the paper. Cheers.